# C# Regex MultiCapture

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to write a C# Regexp which can match line like :

Line -> my text 1 (Sample Text1) (9874)      (1478)

Matches :

- [0] = my text 1
- [1] = Sample Text1
- [2] = 9874
- [3] = 1478

Line -> Thing1 : my text 2 (Text2)   (98631)

Matches :

- [0] = Thing1 : my text 2
- [1] = Text2
- [2] = 98631

Line -> This is a other Sample : mqlsdjflkj (1478)

Matches :

- [0] = This is a other Sample : mqlsdjflkj
- [1] = 1478

I've made many test but can't match multi group ?

I try something like that

```
Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"(.*?)(?:\((.*?)\).*?)*");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the time spent figuring out a complicated Regular Expression, you can often do better by 'manually' doing the parsing.   And it's usually more maintainable.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String[] r1 = MyParser("my text 1 (Sample Text1) (9874) (1478) ");
    String[] r2 = MyParser("Thing1 : my text 2 (Text2) (98631)");
    String[] r3 = MyParser("This is a other Sample : mqlsdjflkj (1478) "); 
}

string[] MyParser(String Input)
{
    String[] RawResult;

    RawResult = Input.Split(new char[] {'(', ')'},  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );

    List<string> Results = new List<string>();

    foreach(String S in RawResult)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(S) == false)
            Results.Add(S.Trim());
    }          

    return Results.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will capture up to 4 groups:

```
Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"(.*?)(?:\((.*?)\)(?:\((.*?)\)(?:\((.*?)\))?)?)?");
```

Comment: Thx, but it doesn't work... :( I try on C# code and into http://regexhero.net/tester/ and nothing work :(

Comment: @Muby: Did you try to double escape `\\(` & `\\)`?